# maven trying to use local repository offline from another computer

Tags: maven

I am trying to use a local repository on another computer.
In a VM, i am connected to tha companies VPN and cna download everything into the local repository. To go offline I use

```
mvn depencency:go-offline
```

and then

```
mvn -o clean install
```

that works well in the VM.
The host maschine is using the same filesystem as the VM.So both computer access the same files on the local repository  And I try to do

```
mvn -o clean install
```

but I get the error

```
Cannot access XXX (XXX) in offline mode and the artifact com.yyy:yyy:pom:yyy has not been downloaded from it before.
```

While its true that its hasn't been ddownloaded. I wonder why it tries to download it, because its already in the local repository and I am using the '-o' offline switch.

How can get maven to not try to download it, even though I never have downloaded it from this computer?

Comment: go-offline goal [is known to have a plenty of related issues](https://issues.apache.org/jira/issues/?jql=project%20%3D%20MDEP%20AND%20component%20%3D%20go-offline)

Comment: Do a full build on the original machine and _then_ use the populated repository.

Comment: @Thorbjørn,   I cant make a full build on the host system, because it hasnt access to the company repository.

Comment: Why does it work for the VM-system, but not for thehost system? Is there any caching or status being saved when downloading dependencies, which is not stored in the repo-tree?

Comment: Can you make a full build _somewhere_?

Comment: Yes, Ia can make a full build on my VM (while connected to the company VPN). The VM is using the same filesystem (irtualBox shared filesystem) as the host, but on the host I am getting the errors. Is there any information stored by maven outside of the local file repository ?

Comment: Your assumption that "go-offline" downloads everything needed is incorrect.

Comment: ok, but mystery remains, why I can build everything on one maschine with the local Repository. But on other maschine with same local Repository, it complains ( I assume if it can build that is has downloaded everything needed)